# "Is equal to" or "equals"

Tags: word-usage

Are both *is equal to* and *equals* similar in meaning? Which is the more natural?

For example, *one plus one equals two* or *one plus one is equal to two*.

Comment: You can also add "is" to the list.

Comment: @skullpatrol: I agree with the answers and comments that say that “equals” and “is equal to” mean the same thing in most situations; always, in strictly mathematical contexts.  Based on my understanding of English, I submit that “is” carries a slightly different connotation and nuance.  ([“It depends on what the meaning of the word _`is’_ is.”](http://news.bbc.co.uk/onthisday/hi/dates/stories/september/21/newsid_2525000/2525339.stm))  For example, Superman _is_ Clark Kent, but I wouldn’t say that they are equal.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct and mean the same. And both are the natural ways of saying it. Use either.

Comment: _Equals_ is _equal_ being a verb, in the present tense. _Is equal to_ is _equal_ being a predicate adjective, with its auxiliary verb in the present tense. English is full of pairs like this, useful if one needs an extra syllable. As @Slkdfj Jfjf succinctly puts it, **Use any.**

Comment: @JohnLawler Could you please look at [this question?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80897/equals-is-equal-to-and-is)

Answer (score 5):

"1+3=4" may be read "one plus three equals four" or "one plus three is equal to four".  Both are correct, and commonly heard.

Comment: However, for "1+3 < 10" we can say "one plus three is less than ten" but not "one plus three lesses ten".

Comment: Re "one plus three equals four" or "one plus three is equal to four" being commonly heard, I'm fairly sure I've never heard anybody say either of those phrases, and doubt I ever will.  Why would anyone bother stating such a trivial sum?

Comment: Well, I guess we all have... back in school at least. And now on English Stack Exchange :)

Comment: so is equal is equal to equals