# Mathematical symbol as simple predicate

Tags: grammaticality

I am translating a paper about a general physics question.  I am not very familiar with physics other than the historical perspective and I am requesting some help with the grammar.  I have a sentence that translates perfectly from the original Spanish as follows:

“At the moment of t1 at which both objects reach the ground, y1(t1)=y2(t1)=0.”

In English, a complete sentence requires a subject and a predicate.  In the above sentence, the subject would be “y1(t1)”, which I guess I don´t have a problem with.  My query is regarding the simple predicate, which in this case would be “=”.  All of the English words in this sentence amount to prepositional phrases.

Is this standard use of language in scientific documents in English?  Should I change the sentence to read something like, “The formula y1(t1)=y2(t1)=0 is satisfied at the moment…”?

Comment: I think that the only problem with your sentence is "At the moment of t1". I would drop "of" and simply say "At the moment t1...". The rest of the sentence looks and sounds fine to me, but then I'm not a native speaker :)

Comment: The "=" in the equation can play the role of the verb, which means this translation is fine (except, as @Armen recommends, I'd drop the "of").

Comment: The symbol '=' in an equation is pronounced _equals_ (always singular present) /'ikwəlz/. The whole equation is pronounced /'waywən əv 'tiwən 'ikwəlz 'waytu əv 'tiwən 'ikwəlz 'zɪro/. The subscripts should be printed sub-, however; i.e, _y₁(t₁) = y₂(t₁) = 0_. Oh, yes, and no _of_, as pointed out.

Comment: Also see  [“Four plus two equals six” (or “is equal to six” or “is six”)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80897)about how to read “4 + 2 = 6”.

Comment: 'At time t₁' would be more usual than 'at moment t₁'.

Comment: I'd say emphatically that the sentence is structured the best possible way and needs no revision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rephrase it to...

> At time t1 when both objects reach the ground [some equation].

Semantically, [some equation] is simply *a statement*, which could normally stand on its own as a complete sentence anyway. Substituting something simpler, such as *"A=B"*, it's obvious that we could convert that to words *("A is equal to B")*. There's no reason to suppose just because OP's form is a little more complex, it needs any additional text (such as *"is true"*, or *"is a satisfied equation"*).

Comment: I think using *moment* is probably ill-advised, as @EdwinAshworth has commented. See [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/moment) sense 3, bearing in mind that this is a physics question.

Comment: You are right.  Edwin Ashworth pointed out that the correct word in this case is "time" and I confirmed on Google.

Comment: I agree with all three of you. I pussyfooted around trying to make the least change I thought was "necessary". I'll change it to reflect what I think we *normally* see in such contexts. I'll just mention that although I *think* most "wordsmiths" would probably demarcate *when both objects reach the ground* with commas, I have the feeling most "technical writers" wouldn't do this. I don't think the original (just one comma at the end) has much to commend it in a technical context.