# Equals / is equal to / is

Tags: differences

Please tell me how to do it correctly.

- Twenty divided by five is four.
- Twenty divided by five equals four.
- Twenty divided by five is equal to four.

Tell me please. Are all the options correct and do you use them all?

Comment: They are all correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Is equal to" or "equals"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71259/is-equal-to-or-equals) (includes 'you can [also use] _is_')

Comment: All are OK in mathematics and there is no difference in that context. However, outside arithmetic, the verb _equal_ is rarely used. When it is, it implies extreme accuracy, which is not true of the others.

Answer (score 1):

> Twenty divided by five is four. Twenty divided by five equals four

both are correct but the last one you have written 'bt' if you mean 'by' then it will be correct too.